# datasource configuration error for Spring 2.5.6 & ojdbc6

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to config datasource in Spring 2.5.6.
My database is oracle 11g and jdbc driver is ojdbc6.
The following is my configuration:

```
<bean id="databaseConnectionPool" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="URL"><value>${jdbc.dburl}</value></property>
    <property name="connectionCacheName" value="PSSMST"/>
    <property name="user"><value>${jdbc.dbusername}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.dbpassword}</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="75"/>
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <props merge="default">
            <prop key="MinLimit">20</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">150</prop>
            <prop key="InitialLimit">20</prop>
        </props>
    </property>


</bean>
```

But when the Tomcat server starts up, I get this message:

> Invalid property 'connectionCachingEnabled' of bean class
>   [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource]: Bean property
>   'connectionCachingEnabled' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

That really makes me upset. I checked the `OracleDataSource` class, of course, the `setConnectionCachingEnabled` method exists.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Any chance that you have multiple versions of ojdbc jars in your WEB-INF/lib directory? or in tomcat's server library etc.,? I suspect if an older version of jar with the OracleDataSource class without this attribute, is being picked by the class loader.

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked the lib folder in tomcat. there only ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar

Comment: Hi Vikdor, you're right. Another jar that come from vendor contains oracle jdbc related classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable reason is that you are using an older version of ODBC than intended. Please check lib folder of your application and also check lib folder of Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've checked lib folder and there only one jdbc driver file. I'm using ojdbc6-11.2.0.3. This version is quite new...

Comment: you're right ! There is another jar contains  oracle driver classes. it came from other vendor for mobile short message sending...